# In SQL Server, how do I make sql using "or" clauses over two connected tables use the correct indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB` which are related by `AID`. `AID` is the primary key in `TableA` and a foreign key in `TableB`.

The following SQL is used to select anything from `TableB` joined to `TableA` where `ADesc` or `BDesc` are like a certain value.

SQL1:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.AID = TableB.AID
WHERE ADesc LIKE 'A0A4D1%' OR BDesc = 'A0A4D1%'
```

- Table A has a clustered index on `AID` (`TableA_PK`)
- Table A has a non-clustered index on `ADesc` (`TableA_I1`)
- Table B has a clustered index on `BID` (`TableB_PK`)
- Table B has a non-clustered index on `BDesc` (`TableB_I1`)

If I separate up the above SQL into two statements (or one statement connected with a UNION as in SQL2), SQL Server will utilise the `TableA_I1` and `TableB_I1` and restrict on `ADesc` or `BDesc` really efficiently.

SQL2:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.AID = TableB.AID
WHERE ADesc LIKE 'A0A4D1%'
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.AID = TableB.AID
WHERE BDesc = 'A0A4D1%'
```

However SQL1 does not use either `TableA_I1` or `TableB_I1` and returns much much slower.

My question is there a way I can get SQL Server to execute SQL1 but use the same indexes and similar execution plan as in SQL2?

I am using SQL Server 2019.

This may seem a strange question which begs the follow question - why don't you just change it to a UNION? 1st, my actual SQL is much more complex and the resulting UNION would be huge so I wanted to see if I could simplify. 2nd, I'm just curious as to why SQL server can't work it out and optimise it itself.

The SQL to create all the tables and indexes is below:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    AID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    ADesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TableA_I1 ON TableA (ADesc ASC)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX TableA_PK ON TableA (AID ASC)
GO

CREATE TABLE TableB
( 
    BID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    AID INT NOT NULL, 
    BDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TableB_I1 ON TableB (BDesc ASC)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX TableB_PK ON TableB (BID ASC)
GO
```

I then threw a few million rows into the tables to make sure there was plenty for it go at!

Comment: FYI - your code uses `UNION` which in general performs terribly, so unless you specifically want its de-duplication behaviour, use `UNION ALL` which will perform much better. And for you union is there actually any need to join the tables?

Comment: Thanks Dale - noted.

Comment: Using an `or` criteria rarely performs well on joins because SQL Server cannot know which index to seek into; also using `select *` is not going to help the query optimizer at all, do you *really* need every column from both tables? Using `union ALL` here is a well-used pattern - but for each table, not joining both; if you need all columns from both tables consider selecting just the *keys* into a temp table and then joining on that.

Comment: "And for you union is there actually any need to join the tables?" - that's a really good question. I've simplified to show the problem - but in reality I don't just have ADesc and BDesc - it is lots of related data which I need in the results (and there are further restrictions).

Comment: SQL server needs up to date statistics for TableA_I1 and TableB_I1 to make decisions based on the distribution of values in them (whether they will filter out a lot of data or a little); have you updated statistics.

Comment: @Stu - "SQL Server cannot know which index to seek into" - I think that gets right down to the nub of my question. Why can't it seek into both and then merge the result together? Appreciate the answer might just be - it doesn't!

Comment: Regarding UNION performance: Perhaps a `UNION ALL` together with an additional `and ADesc not like 'A0A4D1%'` on the second part (to explicitly exclude duplicates) would have better performance. Another approach would to just select and union the record IDs (PKs) as a CTE or subselect and then use those IDs to perform joins to the full data.

Comment: SQL Server uses a cost-based optimiser, it will be evaluating the cardinality of the data based on its statistics and deciding whether it will cost more to seek into a non-covering index and have to do n bookmark lookups on the primary key vs just scanning the table once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try experimenting with the following pattern. Using a temporary table with a primary key means SQL Server will have accurate statistics to use.

```
drop table if exists #aid;
create table #aid(aid int primary key);

insert into #aid(aid)
select aid
from TableA
where ADesc like 'A0A4D1%'
union all
select aid
from TableB
where BDesc = 'A0A4D1';

select a.<columns>, b.<columns>
from #aid x
join TableA a on a.aid = x.aid
join TableB b on b.aid = x.aid;
```

Comment: This is the pattern I have used, marking this as the answer - thanks! As of current the OR restricting over multiple tables appears to trip SQL server into not using the indexes and therefore explicitly splitting this up using a temporary table and either unioning (or simply doing multiple insert statements) is a great way of making it do so. Incidentally multiple ORs on the same table is fine - i.e. if I had ADesc1 and ADesc2 on tableA.

Comment: Yes on the same table, as usual depending on various factors and cardinality, SQL Server can often use an index intersection, ie joining the results of scanning multiple indexes

Comment: I'd love to be able to just attach a debugger and see why SQL Server chooses certain paths. I know the execution plan gives you most of this, but there still feels an element of second guessing the logic.